# MongoDB Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data too long for column 'scenario_order' at row 1

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate

I want to configure `p:inputNumber` to accept only numbers from 1 to 10 :

```
<p:inputNumber id="scenarioOrder" label="scenarioOrder" value="#{userScenarios.userScenarioModel.scenarioOrder}" decimalSeparator="." decimalPlaces="0" minValue="1" maxValue="10" />
```

Entity configuration :

```
@Column(name = "scenario_order")
private Integer scenarioOrder;
```

But when I try to insert into data base the number value I get :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data too long for column 'scenario_order' at row 1
```

Do you know how I can fir this?

Comment: Can you show us your database please? What is the type of `scenario_order`

Comment: @YCF_L It's Integer. See above, please the Entity configuration

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash My mistake. It should be 10. Thanks.

Comment: This is the entity, but I mean in database

Comment: I use MariaDB. The created Filed is BIT which is wrong. Hm.. any idea what configuration should I use to create INT type field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
@Column(name = "scenario_order", columnDefinition = "TINYINT") 
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
private Integer scenarioOrder;
```